# How can I retrieve the net value of a payment intent once i've stored it on Stripe php

Tags: php, stripe-payments

When storing a PaymentIntent Charge on Stripe lets say for `40.00` Stripe fee is $1.46 and the balance of that is 38.54 is there a way I can retrieve this 38.54 balance i've tried selected the PaymentIntent like how it shows in the Stripe Docs but I can only retrieve the price of the charge which is $40.00 not the balance

here's what it looks like

[image: What the PaymentIntent Charge looks like on Stripe]

and here's my retrieving code

`$order_total = sprintf('%.2f', $stripe->paymentIntents->retrieve(
        ''.$paymentIntent->id.'',
            []
          )['amount'] / 100);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct way to get the `net` amount from the API call, however, you could easily obtain both the original `charge amount` and the `fee amount` from payment_intent.

- Use Stripe PaymentIntent [Retrieval API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve)
- [Expand](https://stripe.com/docs/api/expanding_objects) the `payment_intent.charges.data.balance_transaction` to get the balance transaction where you can find the [fee parameter](https://stripe.com/docs/api/balance_transactions/object#balance_transaction_object-fee)

e.g.

```
  curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents/pi_1GmxGNxxxxxWi \
  -u sk_test_uxxxxxxL: \
  -d "expand[]"="charges.data.balance_transaction"
```

You will just need to subtract the payment_intent amount from the fee parameter to get the net amount.

Comment: There is now a Net property on the Balance Transaction.